# Using List::Util first on an array of Moose objects

Tags: arrays, perl, moose

I have an array called `aTestCaseList` which is initialized and filled with (Moose) objects of type "Testcase". As expected I can print out the Attribute `TestName` of every `Testcase` Object in `aTestCaseList`. But when I try to find the first Object in the list named "Test4" using https://perldoc.perl.org/List/Util.html#first I get the following error

> Can't call method "TestName" on an undefined value

Why are the objects in the array suddenly undefined?

```
use Testcase;

my @aTestcaseList=();
for (my $i=1; $i <= 9; $i++) {
  push(@aTestcaseList,Testcase->new("Test".$i));
}
my $sTestcase="Test4";
foreach my $sTestDummy(@aTestcaseList)
{
     #Works as expected and prints: Test1 Test2 Test3 ... Test9
     print $sTestDummy->TestName." "; 
} 
# throws the error:
my $sFindTest=first {$_->TestName eq $sTestcase} @aTestcaseList;

package Testcase;
use Moose;
use namespace::autoclean;

has 'TestName' => (is =>'ro',isa=>'Str');

around BUILDARGS => sub
{
    my $orig = shift;
    my $class = shift;

    if ( @_ == 1 && ! ref $_[0] ) {
        return $class->$orig(TestName => $_[0]);
    }
    else {
        return $class->$orig(@_);
    }
};
__PACKAGE__->meta->make_immutable;
1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to import the function `first` from `List::Util` like

```
use List::Util qw(first);
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. I think I did misinterpret the error message. I thought for some reason the objects itself are undefined.

Comment: Without a declaration for `first`, `first {$_->TestName eq $sTestcase} @aTestcaseList` was interpreted as the `(do {$_->TestName eq $sTestcase})->first(@aTestcaseList)` indirect method call. `$_` is undefined, so `$_->TestName` threw that error.